# Brightness control on keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, brightness, 22.04

The brightness control keys on the laptop keyboard are not identified on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Tried looking up keystrokes using `xev` but the keystrokes are not reflected. The keys work on Windows. I have a clean installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS now.
Laptop model - **HP 15q-ds1000tu**. Keyboard layout is EN-US.

Comment: try adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to boot options

Comment: That didn’t work.

Comment: In addition to that, I’ve also tried adding `acpi_osi=Linux` and creating a blacklist entry in modprobe. None of that worked.

Comment: Along with the two brightness keys, the airplane mode toggle doesn’t work either. A weird thing to note is that, even though the keystroke for the airplane mode toggle isn’t responding, airplane mode turns on when I close and re-open the laptop’s lid; I tried searching the solutions for that problem too but none of those worked.